# Get value from AngularJS $cookies

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a cookie set

```
$cookieStore.put('lastpage', $scope.page);
```

I want to take the value of cookie 'lastpage', and display in html

```
<div>Last page is 'value'</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

```
  $scope.cookie = $cookieStore.get('lastpage');

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div ng-controller="x">
        Cookie Value: {{cookie}}
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**EDIT** Since Angular 1.4 '$cookieStore' is deprecated, so if using that version (or above) the above should be:

```
  $scope.cookie = $cookies.get('lastpage');
```

See the deprecation warning in [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore)

Comment: and how I will put in hmtl? get an angular format if you can

Comment: did have any id or class in div

Answer (score 0):

load the value from cookie in [controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) and bind it in scope.

in js

```
// in controller
$scope.value = $cookieStore.get('lastPage');
```

in html

```
<div>Last page is '{{value}}'</div>
```

Comment: seems exactly what I need

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
app.controller("Welcome!", function($scope, $cookieStore){
    $scope.value = $cookieStore.get('lastpage');
});
```

Put in html:

```
<div ng-controller="Welcome!">{{value}}</div>
```

Thanks!